# What is going on with my Android Navigation drawer activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am building an OpenGL live wallpaper. I decided to have a Navigation Drawer in my main activity since there are a lot of features the user will have access to.

**The problem/issue**
If I press the "hardware" back button to normally close an app the initial fragment that is shown just refreshes and the app never closes. If I hit the home button and go back to the app everything is a black screen. I've searched all throughout Google thinking that maybe I wasn't destroying the MainActivity properly or for a way to terminate a fragment. I've tried calling finish() in the main activity's onDestroy method. I've tried utilizing the remove method from fragment manager in each fragments onDetach method per posts that I've found online. Nothing has worked. I'm stumped. I've set debug points in the main activity on the onDestroy method and on the fragments onDetach method with no error being produced or any information being given. At this point I am clueless. Here's my MainActivity class.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnPostSelectedListener{

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    TextView usrTag, tagrEmail;
    CircleImageView tagrPic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.cLMain, new PreviewFragment()).addToBackStack("PreviewFragment").commit();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        usrTag = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.usrName);
        tagrEmail = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.usrEmail);
        tagrPic = (CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.usrImg);

        Log.i("MainActivity: ", "User Photo: " + getProfilePic(this));

        usrTag.setText(getUserName(getBaseContext()));
        tagrEmail.setText(getUserEmail(getBaseContext()));
        GlideUtils.loadProfileIcon(getProfilePic(getBaseContext()), tagrPic);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragmentClass = PreviewFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_custom) {
            startCustomLabelCreator();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mylabels) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_commLabels) {
            fragmentClass = PostsFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cLMain, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void startCustomLabelCreator(){
        Intent cLC = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateLabel.class);
        startActivity(cLC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostComment(String postKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostLike(String postKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPhotoSelected(String photoUrl) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**My Fragments**

```
    public class PostsFragment extends Fragment implements ConfirmSelectedPhotoListener{

    public static final String TAG = "PostsFragment";
    private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_POSITION = "layoutPosition";
    private int mRecyclerViewPosition = 0;
    private OnPostSelectedListener mListener;


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder> mAdapter;

    public PostsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static PostsFragment newInstance() {
        PostsFragment fragment = new PostsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        Log.d(TAG, "Restoring recycler view position (all): " + mRecyclerViewPosition);
        Query allPostsQuery = FirebaseUtil.getPostsRef();
        mAdapter = getFirebaseRecyclerAdapter(allPostsQuery);
        mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                // TODO: Refresh feed view.
            }
        });


        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> getFirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Query query) {
        return new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
                Post.class, R.layout.post_item, PostViewHolder.class, query) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder,
                                           final Post post, final int position) {
                setupPost(postViewHolder, post, position, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewRecycled(PostViewHolder holder) {
                super.onViewRecycled(holder);
//                FirebaseUtil.getLikesRef().child(holder.mPostKey).removeEventListener(holder.mLikeListener);
            }
        };
    }

    private void setupPost(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final Post post, final int position, final String inPostKey) {
        postViewHolder.setPhoto(post.getThumb_url());
        Log.d(TAG, post.getThumb_url());
        postViewHolder.setText(post.getText());
        postViewHolder.setTimestamp(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                (long) post.getTimestamp()).toString());
        final String postKey;
        if (mAdapter instanceof FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) {
            postKey = ((FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) mAdapter).getRef(position).getKey();
        } else {
            postKey = inPostKey;
        }

        Author author = post.getAuthor();
        postViewHolder.setAuthor(author.getFull_name(), author.getUid());
        postViewHolder.setIcon(author.getProfile_picture(), author.getUid());

        ValueEventListener likeListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postViewHolder.setNumLikes(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId())) {
                    postViewHolder.setLikeStatus(PostViewHolder.LikeStatus.LIKED, getActivity());
                } else {
                    postViewHolder.setLikeStatus(PostViewHolder.LikeStatus.NOT_LIKED, getActivity());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        FirebaseUtil.getLikesRef().child(postKey).addValueEventListener(likeListener);
        postViewHolder.mLikeListener = likeListener;

        postViewHolder.setPostClickListener(new PostViewHolder.PostClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void showComments() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Comment position: " + position);
                mListener.onPostComment(postKey);
            }

            @Override
            public void toggleLike() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Like position: " + position);
                mListener.onPostLike(postKey);
            }

            @Override
            public void savePhotoUrl() {
                //mListener.onPhotoSelected(post.getFull_url());
                showLabelConfirm(post.getFull_url());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter instanceof FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) {
            ((FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) mAdapter).cleanup();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save currently selected layout manager.
        int recyclerViewScrollPosition = getRecyclerViewScrollPosition();
        Log.d(TAG, "Recycler view scroll position: " + recyclerViewScrollPosition);
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_POSITION, recyclerViewScrollPosition);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private int getRecyclerViewScrollPosition() {
        int scrollPosition = 0;
        // TODO: Is null check necessary?
        if (mRecyclerView != null && mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
            scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                    .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        return scrollPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedPhoto(String selectPhoto) {
        mListener.onPhotoSelected(selectPhoto);
    }

    public interface OnPostSelectedListener {
        void onPostComment(String postKey);
        void onPostLike(String postKey);
        void onPhotoSelected(String photoUrl);
    }

    private void showLabelConfirm(String uriBmp) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        PhotoDialogFragment editNameDialogFragment = PhotoDialogFragment.newInstance(uriBmp);
        // SETS the target fragment for use later when sending results
        editNameDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(PostsFragment.this, 300);
        editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnPostSelectedListener) {
            mListener = (OnPostSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnPostSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
    public class PreviewFragment extends RajBaseFragment {


    @Override
    public ISurfaceRenderer createRenderer() {
        return new PreviewRenderer(getContext());
    }


}
```

Which extends:

```
    public abstract class RajBaseFragment extends Fragment implements IDisplay, View.OnClickListener {


    protected FrameLayout mLayout;
    protected ISurface mRajawaliSurface;
    protected ISurfaceRenderer mRenderer;

    public RajBaseFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate the view
        mLayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(getLayoutID(), container, false);

        mLayout.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_loader_container).bringToFront();

        // Find the TextureView
        mRajawaliSurface = (ISurface) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.rajwali_surface);

        // Create the loader


        mRenderer = createRenderer();
        onBeforeApplyRenderer();
        applyRenderer();
        return mLayout;
    }

    protected void onBeforeApplyRenderer() {

    }

    protected void applyRenderer() {
        mRajawaliSurface.setSurfaceRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if (mLayout != null)
            mLayout.removeView((View) mRajawaliSurface);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.rajawali_textureview_fragment;
    }




}
```

I've tried all the recommendations below so far and the primary fragment that is set in the MainActivity's onCreate method still gets refreshed/reloaded when the back button is pressed rather than the app exiting/closing.

Comment: check for is super.onBackPressed() statement called when back button is pressed?

Comment: @SandeepSharma how would I check that or see that in the logcat?

Comment: You can attach debugger point to this statement. The other solution you could think Are focusable views on fragment  handled properly. they might also cause problems as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755550/fragment-pressing-back-button in @Hiren Patel answer.

Comment: If this does not help then post your fragment's relevant code.

Comment: @SandeepSharma Please see my edit

Comment: remove .addToBackStack("PreviewFragment") and try. Your  PreviewFragment's PreviewRenderer might have problems  too.

Comment: PostsFragment code not required as I think

Comment: first try with simple fragment then move to PreviewFragment

Comment: I need PreviewFragment and RajBaseFragment to point exact problem. (Your fragment is somehow adding again in back stack when you are pressing back button)

Comment: Are you using Rajawali library?

Comment: @Ramit yes I am using Rajawali library.

Comment: As dumb as this may sound, I figured out what was wrong. All of the various answers did help in their own way but it ended up being something really rediculous that was causing the refresh/reload of the fragment(s). Apparently the activity with the nav drawer has to be the main activity in the manifest. The default launch activity. I had a separate activity that redirected to the main activity if the user was logged in. So for anyone else that may have the same issue, make sure the nav menu activity is the default activity to avoid refresh on back button pressed.

Comment: No I have some correction. If you are navigating from a some activity to drawer activity you can call finish to close first activity to solve problem. No need to make drawer activity as main activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onNavigationItemSelected` method, you are replacing the current fragment with `fragment` even in cases where `fragment` is null, which has undefined effects. You should not do that.

One fix is to replace this code block:

```
try {
  fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with this one:

```
if (fragmentClass != null) {
  fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cLMain, fragment).addToBackStack().commit();
}
```

(and then leave out the fragment transaction below this point).

Also, there is a call to `finish` in the `onDestroy` method, which probably is not causing the problem but should be taken out because it does not make any sense there.

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, you are also using `addToBackStack` incorrectly. I changed the answer to add the transaction to the back stack here, but you also need to not add to back stack when you set the initial fragment in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:
                 onBackPressed();
                 break;
            }
          return true;
  }
```

replace your onOptionsItemSelected() with mine.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include your first fragment into backstack.

Try to change you fragment transaction line code without `addToBackStack` 
as below:

```
mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.cLMain, new PreviewFragment()).commit();
```

> While adding fragment with `addToBackStack`, this allows back
>   navigation  for added fragment.Because of fragment in backstack, 
>   **empty(black)** activity layout will be displayed.

Change `onBackPressed()` as below which automatically close app after if no any Fragment found in FragmentManager:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.finish();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Also you can see some similar Q/A on below links which helps you get more idea to solve your problem:

[Fragment pressing back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635594/2949612)

[In Fragment on back button pressed Activity is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank)

[Transaction of fragments in android results in blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546098/transaction-of-fragments-in-android-results-in-blank-screen)

It's solved my blank screen problem. Hope its helps you.

Comment: I tried this and it still refreshes/reloads primary fragment when pressing back button

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, hope this helps you, take necessary stuffs which are required for you. Also, try running this project in Android studio, it  works.

https://github.com/asifali22/Navigation_Health/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thenewboston/mynavigation/MainActivity.java

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you. That info was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When user press to back button it'll check fragment manager's backstack and if backstack entity count is bigger than 0 (this means there's a fragment in backstack) it'll popBackStack else it'll finish activity.

If you add your initial fragment to backstack, when user press back button they'll see a blank screen.

Also when you init your activity if you need to put a fragment it's a best practice to check if saved instance state is null. Here i modified some part of your code.

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.cLMain, new PreviewFragment()).commit();
}
```

I hope this'll help you. If you still have problem let me know.

Good luck.

Comment: I tried adding this and it still refreshes the PreviewFragment or any fragment that is set as the primary when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

create subclass for `ISurface` and override `onKeyDown` method like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("Custom View", "onKeyDown");
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be related with the lifecycle...
Try using [**GLSurfaceView**](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html). I believe is  easier for what you want, is special for OpenGL rendering and there is plenty information about it. [Examples](https://gist.github.com/ybakos/4151696), [lifecycle](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html) among [others](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html). Let me know if helped. If not, please, provide more info.

Comment: The OpenGL part doesn't have any issues. It's the main activity with the nav drawer and fragments.