# IllegalStateException with Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a screen where I want to swap two fragments by hiding and showing (**not** replacing them) when certain views are clicked. Here is my code:

```
...
private Fragment currentFragment;
...
private void swapFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (currentFragment != null && !currentFragment.isHidden()) {
        ft.hide(currentFragment);
    }

    if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment);
    } else {
        ft.show(fragment);
    }
    ft.commit();

    currentFragment = fragment;
}
...
```

`R.id.fragment_holder` is a FrameLayout. I do not declare any `<fragment>` tags in my layout. Originally my swap method was simply this...

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment).commit();
```

...but for reasons I won't get into here I want to do show/hide instead of replace.

Logically this should be pretty straightforward: if there's a fragment showing, hide it first. If it's the first time showing this fragment, add it, otherwise show it. Then save the current fragment.

The problem is on first launch, this crashed with an `IllegalStateException` stating the fragment has already been added.

```
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ContactFragment{42263030 #0 id=0x7f0a006d}
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:154)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5242)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ContactFragment{42263030 #0 id=0x7f0a006d}
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1175)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1499)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:957)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1882)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:573)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at com.my.package.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:252)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5233)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2287)
11-12 08:36:49.098: E/AndroidRuntime(27293):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you please show us the `onStart` method of your `Activity` class?

Comment: You should replace or remove fragment before adding new fragment.

Comment: @Homosapiens: Then why are there show and hide APIs?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149446/

Comment: @Homosapiens: that link confirms exactly what I am trying to do. I want to show/hide instead of replace so that I can show it again later if needed without the fragment going through its entire teardown process.

Comment: Did you try checking if fragment is null instead of isAdded()?

Comment: @Rani: Please see the answer I posted. Also, the stack trace makes it clear that it is trying to add a fragment that is already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out my swapping logic works just fine. The problem is actually something with `RadioGroup` in which it's `OnCheckChangedListener` can be called twice for a single check change among its child `RadioButton`s. This produces two `FragmentTransaction`s, the second of which causes the IllegalStateException because it tries to add an already added fragment.

The solution for me was to add

```
if (fragment == currentFragment) return;
```

at the beginning of `swapFragment()`.

Comment: You might want to prefer `if (fragment == null || fragment.equals(currentFragment))`. It might make more sense to compare based on content not pointer.