# Android Fragments switch without destroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have an activity with 3 fragments. Every fragment has a question. 
When i create the activity I'm calling .add(...) method for the first fragment. For the others i call .replace(...) method with addToBackStack(...) method.

So i have this situation in the backstack:

**.add(Frag1)**

--> Frag 1

**.replace(..., Frag2, ...)**

-->Frag2

-->Frag1

**.replace(..., Frag3, ...)**

--> Frag3

--> Frag2

--> Frag1

Now, when I'm at the third fragment and then go back I'm popping it from the stack. I want to preserve the third fragment so if i go back to the second and then go next to the third i want to have the question answered and not to call again another onCreate().

I want to create a sort of switch of the fragments. Is it possible? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `fragment` once and Show/Hide it depending on your needs.

See [hide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.app.Fragment)) & [show](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.app.Fragment)) from [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) docs

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149446/android-fragments-when-to-use-hide-show-or-add-remove-replace)

Answer (score 0):

How about you use viewpager instead, you will need to:

- Disable paging by swipe, so you can change the page programmatically
- Load all pages at once (set setOffscreenPageLimit your pages count), so that each page keeps its state