# If I hide/show a fragment instead of replacing it, would that cause more load on UI rendering?

Tags: android, performance, fragment

For Example:

```
Fragment prevFragment = getSupportedFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
getSupportedFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .hide(prevFragement)
    .add(R.id.container, fragment, null)
    .commit();
```

Comment: doesn't really sound like a good idea, keeping potentially irrelevant code in memory, even if a fragment isn't visible it will still go through lifecycle events

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Fragments: When to use hide/show or add/remove/replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149446/android-fragments-when-to-use-hide-show-or-add-remove-replace)